# How to read nfc data using the react native expo project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

My project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGFg.png)

I tried the react-native-nfs-manager library. Nothing is working out yet

Creating a project using the npc create expo-app

Added to the plugin (app.json)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0VIB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a extra configuration in the android folder, generate the folder and look for AndroidManifest.xml and try this code.

Reference documentation:
https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager

Comment: as I understand it, I have an expo go project